# Postgres - Add seconds to timestamptz, value from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a column `a` which is a `timestamptz`. Also, I have a column `b` which is an `integer`, which denoted the number of seconds to be added to `a`. I want to do have the date of `a + b`.

Is this the the desired way?

```
select a + (b::TEXT || ' seconds')::INTERVAL from table;
```

It's weird that we have to manually construct a string here, I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
select a + b * interval '1' second
```

You can multiple intervals by numbers.

Note:  This can work with the single quotes around either just the number or the "1 second".  These are equivalent:

```
select a + b * interval '1' second
select a + b * interval '1 second'
```

I should note that commonly intervals are used with only one time unit.  So, Postgres accepts either of the above.  For multiple time units, then you need a single string:

```
select a + interval '1 day 1 hour'
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `interval '1 second'` instead of `interval '1' second`?

Comment: Clever, thanks! I think you need to change to '1 second`. I'll accept the answer.